# Add CheckBox to a Canva Kivy

Tags: python, checkbox, kivy

I need to add a checkbox to this Kivy Canvas but it don"t know how to do it properly. I need the checkbox to display the name of all the file in the folder Data. Then the user check the file he wants and then by pressing a button (here the red one) it return a list of the file name and call some functions. Here is where i am right now.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.uix.label import Label

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView

from kivy.uix.popup import Popup



from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget.
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty




 import time
 import os

Builder.load_string('''<Game>
    ShootButton:


<ShootButton>

    Image: 
        source: 'logo.jpg'
        allow_stretch: True
        size: 300,300
        pos: 300, 400


    Image: 
        source: 'livre.jpg'
        allow_stretch: True
        size: 350, 350
        pos: 490,130

    Button:
        text: "Modifier Correspondance"
        size: 240,50
        font_size: 20
        pos: 100,300
        background_color :0, 1, 0, 1,
        on_press: root.shoot()

    Button:
        text: "Liste Fichiers"
        size: 240,50
        font_size: 20
        pos: 100,400
        background_color :0, 1, 0, 1,
        on_press: root.fire_popup()

    Button:
        text: "Ajouter Fichier"
        size: 240,50
        font_size: 20
        pos: 100,200
        background_color :0, 1, 0, 1,
        on_press: root.shoot2()

    Button:
        text: "Generer PDF"
        size: 180,50
        font_size: 20
        pos: 580,60
        background_color :1, 0, 0, 1,
        on_press: root.display()



         ''')


 Window.size = (900, 600)
 Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)




class Game(Widget):
    pass


class SimplePopup(Popup):
    pass

class SimplePopup2(Popup):
    pass

class ShootButton(Widget):

    def shoot(self):
        shooting = Bullet()
        shooting.bullet_fly()

    def shoot2(self):
        shooting = Bullet()
        shooting.bullet_fly2()

class Bullet(Widget):
    def bullet_fly(self):
        print("test")


    def bullet_fly2(self):
        os.system("open .")





class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Game()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's a lot of things you're asking for.

First we will need to create a layout with the labels as the files name and the checkbox to the corresponding file.

For this I'll use GridLayout, but you can do it as you want. In this layout we will need to get the files list, create the labels with the checkboxes, and, eventually, see what boxes are marked. So we will create a class with three functions and use a dict to link each box to its file:

```py
class Grid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2

        self.files = self.get_files()
        self.check_list = {}
        self.create_checks()


    def get_files(self):
        # Get your files herre
        return ['Hi', 'how', 'are', 'you?']

    def create_checks(self):
        # Create the checkboxes
        for item in self.files:
            self.add_widget(Label(text=item))
            self.check_list[item] = CheckBox()
            self.add_widget(self.check_list[item])

    def get_actives(self):
        # Check who is active (marked)
        actives = []
        for item in self.check_list:
            if self.check_list[item].state == 'down':
                actives.append(item)

        return actives
```

Then we will ned to pass this class to our main content to display it for the user. For this I'll use a popup, but again, you can do as you please. So I'll start adding our content to a popup, and creating a function to call it.

```py
class ShootButton(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        # Create popup with grid content
        self.pop_content = Grid()
        self.popup = Popup(title='', separator_height=0,
                           size_hint=(.8, .6),
                           content=self.pop_content)

    def open_pop(self):
        # You guessed! Opens the popup
        self.popup.open()
```

Moslty done, now we just have to check which checkboxes are marked when the button is pressed. So I'll get your function `display` and use it to call our `get_actives` function:

```
def display(self):
    actives = self.pop_content.get_actives()
    print(actives)
```

And here is the full code:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import os

Builder.load_string('''<Game>
    ShootButton:


<ShootButton>

    Image: 
        source: 'logo.jpg'
        allow_stretch: True
        size: 300,300
        pos: 300, 400


    Image: 
        source: 'livre.jpg'
        allow_stretch: True
        size: 350, 350
        pos: 490,130

    Button:
        text: "Modifier Correspondance"
        size: 240,50
        font_size: 20
        pos: 100,300
        background_color :0, 1, 0, 1,
        on_press: root.shoot()

    Button:
        text: "Liste Fichiers"
        size: 240,50
        font_size: 20
        pos: 100,400
        background_color :0, 1, 0, 1,
        on_press: root.fire_popup()

    Button:
        text: "Ajouter Fichier"
        size: 240,50
        font_size: 20
        pos: 100,200
        background_color :0, 1, 0, 1,
        on_press: root.shoot2()

    Button:
        text: "Generer PDF"
        size: 180,50
        font_size: 20
        pos: 580,60
        background_color :1, 0, 0, 1,
        on_press: root.display()
         ''')

Window.size = (900, 600)
Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)


class Game(Widget):
    pass


class SimplePopup(Popup):
    pass


class SimplePopup2(Popup):
    pass


class Grid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2

        self.files = self.get_files()
        self.check_list = {}
        self.create_checks()

    def get_files(self):
        # Get your files here
        return ['Hi', 'how', 'are', 'you?']

    def create_checks(self):
        # Create the checkboxes
        for item in self.files:
            self.add_widget(Label(text=item))
            self.check_list[item] = CheckBox()
            self.add_widget(self.check_list[item])

    def get_actives(self):
        # Check who is active (marked)
        actives = []
        for item in self.check_list:
            if self.check_list[item].state == 'down':
                actives.append(item)

        return actives


class ShootButton(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        # Create popup with grid content
        self.pop_content = Grid()
        self.popup = Popup(title='Choose files', separator_height=0,
                           size_hint=(.8, .6),
                           content=self.pop_content)

    def shoot(self):
        shooting = Bullet()
        shooting.bullet_fly()
        self.open_pop()

    def shoot2(self):
        shooting = Bullet()
        shooting.bullet_fly2()

    def fire_popup(self):
        pass

    def open_pop(self):
        # You guessed! Opens the popup
        self.popup.open()

    def display(self):
        actives = self.pop_content.get_actives()
        print(actives)


class Bullet(Widget):
    def bullet_fly(self):
        print("test")

    def bullet_fly2(self):
        os.system("open .")


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Game()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Strange, did you just copy the full code in this answer? Are you using python 2?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am working with Python 2.7 so i modify super. I don't see the checkbox but i got when i click the button a blank list popping up